# How can I change the password prompt in a self-extracting WinRAR archive?

Tags: archiving, winrar, password-protection, self-extracting

I create a password-protected self-extracting archive using WinRAR. When I open the archive the executable asks me for a password. How can I change "Enter password for the encrypted file." to a custom prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution available for Windows:

1. Generate your self-extracting archive using WinRAR as you usually
   do. Download [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) for Windows.
2. Open the file created within step 1 in Resource Hacker.
3. Edit the main dialog resource 1031
   of the dialog "GETPASSWORD1" in order to change the text of the
   static control, which is the first control of the dialog. You are
   also able to edit the caption of the dialog prompting for a
   password.
4. Click on File/Save.
5. Click on Action/Compile.
6. Click on File/Save.

You can transfer these steps using any other resourde editor like [Resedit](http://www.resedit.net/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible: most parts of the SFX archives can be customized, but for this part there is simply no command or interface available to change it. You can use the `-p` switch when calling the executable for suppressing the dialog (e.g. `compressed_file.exe -pmypass`), but that would defeat the purpose of the password protection.

If you do want password protection, you would I guess need some kind of installer creation software. With e.g. the [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) you can configure it similarly to an SFX archive, plus it allows for custom user prompts with which you can mimic the password protection.

Comment: I would like to change the self-extracting executable created by WinRAR.

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm: I know, but again, as far as I know I don't think it is possible. If suppressing the password isn't an option, then I see no other option next to looking into different solutions.